# How best would I store a variable that will be used multiple times throughout the execution of a method and will stay the same?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I'm handling a pan gesture with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and I want to know the initial point every time the function is called when the view is panned. So I save it into a variable and for each additional time that function is called I can just access this unchanging variable, as the original value I got it from (say, the first time the function is called I save its value) will be changed as the function gets called more.

Static variables don't seem to work as if I do the following:

```
static CGFloat originalImageTopPosition = CGRectGetMinY(self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.frame);
```

I get:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant.

I could use a `property`, but if there were tons of cases where I needed things like this, it would seem like a poor choice to clutter up my list of properties with random saved values.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a static variable without initializing it (or initialize to zero or something), then in an initialization method set it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean by an initialization method?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation. For your example of handling a pan gesture, you can assign the value to a local variable inside an if clause like this:

```
CGPoint point;
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    point = [sender locationInView:nil];
}
```

This will only be called once during a pan gesture, so you can use this point to do calculations during the panning stage of the gesture.

Comment: How would I access that outside the scope of that if statement?

Comment: @Aloha64, sorry, yeah, you would have to declare it outside the if statement, but set the value inside. Then you can access it in the rest of the method. I've edited to show that.

Answer (score 0):

well floats are a little tricker, generally you will use some sort of magic value, assuming that you will want 0 to be valid there is a little float trick you can use

```
static float blah = 0/0.f;

if (blah!=blah) 
{
    blah = 3.4;
}
```

basically you use a compile time constant that is a NaN, then NaN!=NaN... then you get to set at run time.

so for your case it would be...

```
static CGFloat originalImageTopPosition = 0.0/0.0;

if(originalImageTopPosition!=originalImageTopPosition)
{ 
    originalImageTopPosition = CGRectGetMinY(self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.frame);
}
```

Edit - just thought of a less cryptic way...

```
static CGFloat * originalImageTopPositionPtr = NULL;
static CGFloat originalImageTopPosition = 0.0/0.0;

if(!originalImageTopPositionPtr)
{
    originalImageTopPosition = CGRectGetMinY(self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.frame);
    originalImageTopPositionPtr = &originalImageTopPosition;
}
```

and an even less cryptic way...

```
static BOOL originalImageTopPositionInited = NO;
static CGFloat originalImageTopPosition = 0.0/0.0;

if(!originalImageTopPositionInited)
{
    originalImageTopPosition = CGRectGetMinY(self.imageBeingOverlayedScrollView.frame);
    originalImageTopPositionInited = YES;
}
```

Comment: although in this example you are almost certainly not going to gain anything by this complexity, only if CGRectGetMinY took a considerable amount of time and always returned the same value would you want to consider this.